# How can I use a .URDF sensor on a .SDF robot on ROS and Gazebo?

Tags: simulation, ros, sensors, firmware, gazebo-simu

maybe it's a silly question but I am a beginner.

I have a Firmware of a flight controller called PX4, here it is: https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot
That Firmware contains SITL Gazebo tools so I can simulate in gazebo some models which are included in the Firmware in .sdf format. They are in Firmware/Tools/sitl_gazebo/models.

I also have a laser sensor which is a Teraranger Tower Evo, which is a laser sensor and has a description for Gazebo in .URDF and .XACRO, here it is: https://github.com/Terabee/teraranger_description

So, the idea is to join the sensor to one of those robots but I can't find how to do it.
Even I am not able to spawn the sensor in gazebo as standalone model or read data from it (I think it is because I am not spawning it correctly). I did a launcher to spawn a urdf model, it is added to gazebo but not the mesh and it does not do anything.

What occurred to me is to add laser sensors that behave as similar as possible to the one I want to use, but that would be in case I can't add the original one.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself,
The problem was that the .URDF file I was trying to add to my robot didn't has an  tag, so Gazebo was just skipping that.

I used the .URDF of the repo, so I was assuming it was ok and the problem was that I didn't knew how to add it, but the problem was in the .URDF file of the repo.